# Help, please! trigonometry and linear system

Tags: general-topology

I have this exercise; can anyone help me please?

$\def\arsinh{\operatorname{arsinh}}$
We have 
$$\forall x,x' \in \mathbb{R}, |\tanh (x) - \tanh (x')| \leq |x-x'|$$
and 
$$\forall x,x' \in \mathbb{R}, |\arsinh (x) - \arsinh (x')| \leq |x-x'|$$
Prove that the linear system 
$$
\begin{cases}
x - \dfrac{1}{3} \tanh (x) + \dfrac{1}{4} \arsinh (y) & = 0\\
4x - \tanh (y) + \dfrac{3}{4} \arsinh (x) & = 0
\end{cases}
$$
admits a unique solution in the space $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|)$, and determine this solution.

Note that $\arsinh$ is the “inverse hyperbolic sine”.

Comment: What are "thx , argsh x" ??

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $\tanh$ (tangens hyperbolicus) and ${\rm arsinh}$ (area sinus hyperbolici).

Comment: $th$ is $tangh$ and $argsh$ is Argument Sinus Hyperbolic).$Argsh(x) = Ln(x +\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ ) so Argsh isn't arcsin.

Comment: There is a problem in my question?

Comment: Yes @luluuuu , there is: you use undefined non-standard symbols. It is usually denoted $\;\tanh x=$ hyperbolic tangent of $\,x\,$, $\;\arcsin \text h x=$ hyperbolic arcsine and etc.

Comment: can any one help me please.